# Get options of component by plugin

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

In my component i have this option (my_plugin)

```
<script>
  export default {
    ready () {
      // ...
    },
    my_plugin: 'test'
  }
</script>
```

In my plugin, i need get 'my_plugin', how can I do this?

```
export default function (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$plugin = (key) => {
        console.log(this.$options.my_plugin)
        return key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set the component up as a global component:

```
Vue.component('your-component', {
    ready () {
      // ...
    },
    my_plugin: 'test'
})
```

then you can retrieve it on the vue instance:

```
var YourComponent = Vue.component('your-component')
```

and access the my_plugin param:

```
YourComponent.$options.my_plugin
```

Comment: I make this [https://forum.vuejs.org/t/get-options-of-component-by-plugin/3294/4](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/get-options-of-component-by-plugin/3294/4)